# Why does a function in my object return undefined?

Tags: javascript, object

Consider this code:

```
var MSE = {
    Module : {}
};

MSE.Module = (function() {

    'use-strict';

    var app = {

        tabsPre : function() {

            var tabsPre = {
                init : function() {

                },
                changeTab : function(arg) {
                    return arg;
                }
            };

            tabsPre.init();
            return tabsPre;
        }
    };

    return app;

})();

console.log( MSE.Module.tabsPre() );
console.log( MSE.Module.tabsPre().changeTab() ); // undefined
console.log( MSE.Module.tabsPre.changeTab() ); // Uncaught TypeError: MSE.Module.tabsPre.changeTab is not a function
```

I am trying to access `changeTab()` in the `tabsPre` object, but I don't seem to be able to. The last two `console.log` statements aren't giving me what I had hoped for. How can I do this?

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xhb16qL6/

In the first `console.log`, I can see the function is there:

[image]

Any help or guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be great. I'm probably having a dumb day and can't see it.

Thanks,
Mikey

Comment: `tabsPre` is a function. Why do you expect `MSE.Module.tabsPre.changeTab()` to work?

Comment: `changeTab` expects an argument. So your second console is `undefined`. Pass it any arg like `MSE.Module.tabsPre().changeTab(1)`

Comment: Just trying anything...even stupid things.

Comment: Let init return some value for `tabspre()` in case you don't execute `changeTab()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ChangeTab return the args its passed to it and it print undefined because you didn't pass any arguments, try:

```
console.log(MSE.Module.tabsPre().changeTab("args"))  //"args"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log( MSE.Module.tabsPre() );
```

this logs the tabsPre object you are returning

```
console.log( MSE.Module.tabsPre().changeTab() );
```

this logs the result of `MSE.Module.tabsPre().changeTab()` which is `undefined` as you didn't pass an argument

```
console.log( MSE.Module.tabsPre.changeTab() );
```

this causes an error as `MSE.Module.tabsPre` is a function, and therefore you cannot access properties of it, as they don't exist

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript dosen't check for the number of arguments.

Suppose I have a method, say `add` and defined like this:

```
function add(arg1, arg2){

}
```

I call this method like in 3 different ways, lets assume:

```
1) add(1,2)   // Works just fine

2) add(1,2,3) // My third argument is ignored.

3) add(1)    // 2nd expected parameter is taken to be `undefined`
```

Your problem is scenario number 3.

Your `changeTab` method expects ONE argument. If you dont pass any in your call to `changeTab`, you see `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The `changeTab ()` function expects an argument. The code then returns the argument passed once it's called. Since you didn't pass an argument, then `undefined` is returned.

Try passing an argument :)